# Access Denied When loading python from Windows with Azure Data Studio

Tags: python, azure-data-studio

I am trying to use a local version of python with Azure Data Studio and I receive this message when I try to use it.

WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" -c "import platform;print(platform.python_version())" Access is denied

I turned off aliasing for Microsoft Store download and can't find anything on the issue with Google beyond that

Comment: I expect this is due to the fact that "WindowsApps" requires admin priviliges. I have the same issue on my work PC so I cannot test this.